# Replacing values in a list based on a condition

Tags: r, list

I have a list of values called squares and would like to replace all values which are 0 to a 40.

I tried:

```
replace(squares, squares==0, 40)
```

but the list remains unchanged

Answer (score 2):

If it is a `list`, then loop through the `list` with `lapply` and use `replace`

```
squares <- lapply(squares, function(x) replace(x, x==0, 40))
squares
#[[1]]
#[1] 40  1  2  3  4  5

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#[[3]]
#[1] 40  1  2  3
```

#### data

```
squares <- list(0:5, 1:6, 0:3)
```

Comment: thanks a lot...I was playing with the lapply function but didn't occur to me that I could put the replace in there

Answer (score 0):

I think for this purpose, you can just treat it as if it were a vector as follows:

```
squares=list(2,4,6,0,8,0,10,20)
squares[squares==0]=40
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 6

[[4]]
[1] 40

[[5]]
[1] 8

[[6]]
[1] 40

[[7]]
[1] 10

[[8]]
[1] 20
```